# Text Shadow in Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, css

I'm coding a webpage and here is how it looks in Firefox, Safari, Opera, and Chrome.

*removed dead ImageShack link*

and here is how it looks in Internet Explorer (brace yourselves)

*removed dead ImageShack link*

Where is the Text-shadow for Internet Explorer? This is driving me crazy! As you can see, this page kinda relies on it to look good (Not to mention the header-image looks like crap on IE as well)

For example, I tried this (http://pastebin.ca/1994660) and it didn't work.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

    <title>Jacob's CTF Highscores</title>
<!--[if IE]><style type="text/css">



</style>
<![endif]-->
<style>
body {
background: url("bg.png") #6d6d6d;
background-repeat:repeat-x;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.DropShadow(
      offx=1, offy=1, color=#000000);
}
#title {
    background: url("title.png");
    width:450px;
    height:74px;
}
* {padding:0;margin:0;}
#mainwrap {
margin:0 auto;
width:800px;
}
.whole {
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
border:4px solid rgba(201, 201, 201, 0.5);
padding:5px;
margin-bottom:10px;
}
.scores {
width:77%;
padding:0;margin:0;
border:4px solid #5E5E5E;
background:#c2c2c2;
float:left;
}

.navigation {
width:20%;
padding:0;margin:0;
border:4px solid #5E5E5E;
float:left;
margin-right:5px;
}
.navigation ul {

list-style:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
background:#c2c2c2;
}

.navigation ul li {
display:block;
margin:0;
padding:0;
font-family:tahoma;
}
.mainlead {
text-transform:uppercase;
font-family:tahoma;
text-align:center;
color:#78CF46;
font-weight:bold;
text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #000;
padding:5px;
background:#A3A3A3;
border-bottom:1px solid #5E5E5E;
}
#menutitle {
text-align:center;
color:#005D9C;
font-weight:bold;
text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #000;
padding:5px;
background:#A3A3A3;
border-bottom:1px solid #5E5E5E;
}
.navigation ul li a {
display:block;
padding:5px;
text-transform:uppercase;
color:yellow;
font-size:16px;
text-align:left;
font-weight:bold;
text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #000;
text-decoration:none;
}
.navigation ul li a:hover {
color:#fff;
background:#B0B0B0;
}
#boards {
border-collapse:collapse;
width:100%;
font-family:tahoma;
font-size:16px;
text-align:left;
font-weight:bold;
text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #000;
}
#boards td {
border-right:1px solid #5E5E5E;
text-align:center;
padding:5px;
}
#head {
border:0px;
color:#CC4949;
}
tr.thescores {
border-top:1px solid #5E5E5E;
color:#478FF5;
}
#first {
color:#C2C20E;
}
#second {
color:#9C9C9C;
}
#third {
color:#CD7F32;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>


<div id="mainwrap">
<div id="title"></div>
<div class="whole">
<div class="navigation">

    <div class="navwrap">

<ul>
<li id="menutitle"><div id="leaderboards">Leaderboards</div></li>
<li><a title="How many points you have." class="current" href="?view=overall">Overall</a></li>
<li><a title="How many captures you've made." href="?view=captures">Captures</a></li>
<li><a title="Total kills by adding tags, explodes, and mines." href="?view=kills">Kills</a></li>
<li><a title="How many tags you've made on your side." href="?view=tags">Tags</a></li>
<li><a title="How many people you've blown up with TNT." href="?view=explodes">Explodes</a></li> 
<li><a title="How many people you've killed with your mines." href="?view=mines">Mines</a></li>
</ul>


        </div>

</div>

<div class="scores">
<div class='mainlead'>Overall Leaderboards</div>

<table id="boards">
<tr id="head"><td>Rank</td><td>Username</td><td>Points</td><td style="width:80px;">Games</td> <td style="width:80px;">Avg. Won</td> </tr>
<tr id="first" class="thescores"><td>1</td><td style="text-align:left">Guard</td><td>423</td><td>12</td><td>1.4%</td> </tr>
<tr id="second" class="thescores"><td>2</td><td style="text-align:left">Jacob_</td><td>413</td><td>12</td><td>1.4%</td> </tr>
<tr id="third" class="thescores"><td>3</td><td style="text-align:left">NoobRUS</td><td>407</td><td>12</td><td>1.4%</td> </tr>
<tr class="thescores"><td>4</td><td style="text-align:left">Aanum</td><td>351</td><td>12</td><td>1.4%</td> </tr>
<tr class="thescores"><td>5</td><td style="text-align:left">Pandora</td><td>320</td><td>12</td><td>1.4%</td> </tr>
<tr class="thescores"><td>6</td><td style="text-align:left">Minec</td><td>300</td><td>12</td><td>1.4%</td> </tr>
<tr class="thescores"><td>7</td><td style="text-align:left">warptera</td><td>275</td><td>12</td><td>1.4%</td> </tr>
<tr class="thescores"><td>4</td><td style="text-align:left">Aanum</td><td>351</td><td>12</td><td>1.4%</td> </tr>
<tr class="thescores"><td>5</td><td style="text-align:left">Pandora</td><td>320</td><td>12</td><td>1.4%</td> </tr>
<tr class="thescores"><td>6</td><td style="text-align:left">Minec</td><td>300</td><td>12</td><td>1.4%</td> </tr>
<tr class="thescores"><td>7</td><td style="text-align:left">warptera</td><td>275</td><td>12</td><td>1.4%</td> </tr>
<tr class="thescores"><td>4</td><td style="text-align:left">Aanum</td><td>351</td><td>12</td><td>1.4%</td> </tr>
<tr class="thescores"><td>5</td><td style="text-align:left">Pandora</td><td>320</td><td>12</td><td>1.4%</td> </tr>
<tr class="thescores"><td>6</td><td style="text-align:left">Minec</td><td>300</td><td>12</td><td>1.4%</td> </tr>
<tr class="thescores"><td>7</td><td style="text-align:left">warptera</td><td>275</td><td>12</td><td>1.4%</td> </tr>
<tr class="thescores"><td>4</td><td style="text-align:left">Aanum</td><td>351</td><td>12</td><td>1.4%</td> </tr>
<tr class="thescores"><td>5</td><td style="text-align:left">Pandora</td><td>320</td><td>12</td><td>1.4%</td> </tr>
<tr class="thescores"><td>6</td><td style="text-align:left">Minec</td><td>300</td><td>12</td><td>1.4%</td> </tr>
<tr class="thescores"><td>7</td><td style="text-align:left">warptera</td><td>275</td><td>12</td><td>1.4%</td> </tr>
<tr class="thescores"><td>4</td><td style="text-align:left">Aanum</td><td>351</td><td>12</td><td>1.4%</td> </tr>
<tr class="thescores"><td>5</td><td style="text-align:left">Pandora</td><td>320</td><td>12</td><td>1.4%</td> </tr>
<tr class="thescores"><td>6</td><td style="text-align:left">Minec</td><td>300</td><td>12</td><td>1.4%</td> </tr>
<tr class="thescores"><td>7</td><td style="text-align:left">warptera</td><td>275</td><td>12</td><td>1.4%</td> </tr>
<tr class="thescores"><td>4</td><td style="text-align:left">Aanum</td><td>351</td><td>12</td><td>1.4%</td> </tr>
<tr class="thescores"><td>5</td><td style="text-align:left">Pandora</td><td>320</td><td>12</td><td>1.4%</td> </tr>
<tr class="thescores"><td>6</td><td style="text-align:left">Minec</td><td>300</td><td>12</td><td>1.4%</td> </tr>
<tr class="thescores"><td>7</td><td style="text-align:left">warptera</td><td>275</td><td>12</td><td>1.4%</td> </tr>

</table>
</div>


 <div style="clear:both;"></div></div> </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you feel you absolutely have to hack Ie to get text-shadows working (instead of slightly altering your colours) take a look at this » http://www.fetchak.com/ie-css3/

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You could use a filter in your css like so:

```
filter:DropShadow(Color=#000000, OffX=1, OffY=1)
```

Usage:

```
{FILTER: DropShadow(Color=color, OffX=offX, OffY=offY, Positive=positive)}
```

- Color is the name or RGB value of the color for the shadow.
- OffX and OffY are the number of pixels to offset the shadow from the object. Positive integers move the shadow to the right or down. Negative integers move the image to the left or up.
- Positive can be set to 1 or 0. For normal objects, Positive=1 creates a normal drop shadow and Positive=0 creates a shadow within the non-transparent region with the shadow direction reversed. For transparent objects, the reverse is true.

[Source](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/creating_drop_shadows_using_style_sheets_text_effects_in_internet_explorer.php3)

[Demo](http://www.jegsworks.com/examples/demodhtml/filter-dropshadow.htm)

Comment: Is this right? <!--[if IE]>
<style type="text/css">
.mainlead {
FILTER: DropShadow(Color=#000, OffX=1, OffY=1, Positive=1);
}
</style>
<![endif]-->

Comment: Yup, but use the full hex value for the color or it will get screwed up, ie: `#000000` for black

Comment: That demo link appears to be broken.

Comment: @evanrmurphy Looks like the demo has moved: http://www.jegsworks.com/examples/demodhtml/filter-dropshadow.htm

Comment: That made the text look horrible.

Answer (score 14):

Shadows made by filter:DropShadow aren't looking good.

I use another element with position:absolute when I need a good-loking shadow:

```
.sample {position:relative}

.sample p{position:relative;z-index:2;text-shadow:1px 1px 3px #000;}

.sample p.shadow{position:absolute;zoom:1;z-index:1;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropShadow(color=#000000,offX=1,offY=1)
    progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=25)
    progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(pixelradius=2.15, enabled='true');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropShadow(color=#000000,offX=1,offY=1)"
    "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=25)"
    "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(pixelradius=2.15, enabled='true')";
    color: #111111;
    top:-2px;
    left:-2px;
}

*|html .sample p.shadow{display:none} /*hidden in other browsers*/

<div class="sample">
 <p>text</p>
 <p class="shadow">text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This works perfect when others didn't. thanks for the full html + CSS!

Comment: Excellent solution.  It made the shadow look a bit chunky in webkit browsers so I did a .shadow { display:none } and then added the shadow styles within a conditional IE statement and of course display:block;

Answer (score 5):

IE doesn't use the text-shadow property.  You can alternately use filter as shows [here](http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/css/cross-browser-drop-shadows).

Answer (score 2):

IE does use text-shadow, at least since IE 10.  You have to have all three distances set, (note the third value has "px", where the questioner didn't have the px, I didn't test to see if that matters, though):

```
.shadow{
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #FFFFFF;
}
```

I also recommend having this meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Doesn't seem to work in IE 9 and prior.  Maybe the questioner was working in IE9.

Comment: Probably IE8, IE9 was released in March 2011.