# strange background color appearing on text hover

Tags: html, css

Has anybody seen something like this before? I've no idea what's causing it.

The "normal" state:

[image: normal :D]

The text "hover" state:

[image: hover D:]

See that little glow around the download text?

Here's the code:

```
.postRow .post .postThumb {
    background: #222;
    display: block;
    width: 267px;
    height: 153px;
    position: relative;
}

.postRow .post .cover {
    background: #222 url(../images/postCover.jpg) no-repeat;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 235px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    display: none;
    width: 267px;
    height: 153px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

.postRow .post .cover .livePreview a {
    float: left;
    color: #e9eff4;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
    margin: 65px 0px 65px 51px;
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}

.postRow .post .cover .livePreview a:hover {
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000, 0 1px 7px rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
}

.postRow .post .cover .download a {
    float: left;
    color: #ff6464;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
    margin: 65px 9px 65px 20px;
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}

.postRow .post .cover .download a:hover {
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000, 0 1px 7px rgba(237,105,105,0.6);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "problem" is caused by the below snippet of code:

```
.postRow .post .cover .download a:hover {
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000, 0 1px 7px rgba(237,105,105,0.6);
}
```

I believe.  Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Seeing as that is his only `:hover` statement, it has to be.

Comment: there are actually two :hover statements, hence my doubt (the second is right at the bottom of the paste)

Comment: The text shadow isn't causing it. It happens even if I just use a text-decoration.

Comment: I see, well in that case perhaps it's a browser/OS issue.  Does it happen on all browsers/systems?

Comment: does commenting out this rule fix the problem?

Comment: Yep. Removing any hover effect fixes it so it's definitely the hover causing it! Perhaps a bug? I've only got Chrome installed atm so I'll do some digging in other browsers.

Comment: I don't think it is a bug, I think that's how the hover rule is supposed to be interpreted - might want to check the CSS regulation though.  If this truly is the answer, would you mind accepting it? :)

Comment: I've addded a background property to the class and that's instantly fixed it. I guess I'll keep it like that then. Strange bug :S wish I knew exactly what caused it!

Comment: I'm still not sure it is a bug, but as long as you've found a way to fix it, I think we're all happy here :)

Answer (score 0):

Does this issue happen in all web browsers?  Or is it happening in just one?  *(i.e. Internet Explorer?)*

If it's happening in Internet Explorer, you may want to consider using the **filter** method: http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/css/cross-browser-drop-shadows

More information about that can be found here, as well:
[Text Shadow in Internet Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205478/text-shadow-in-internet-explorer)