# How does this site render fonts so well?

Tags: fonts, rendering

http://www.addthis.com/

The big font at the top looks so nice. even on windows. I noticed that they didnt do it for the other fonts on the page... is it flash content or something?

Answer (score 3):

Using Firebug or Chrome inspection tools, you can see that the style definition, for the h2 tag (the page header) is :

```
h2 {
font-family: "HelveticaNeueBold","HelveticaNeue-Bold","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,"open sans",arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 36px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 700;
line-height: 1.2em;
word-wrap: break-word;
color: black;
letter-spacing: -0.04em;
}
.hp-banner-b h2 {
margin: 0 0 5px 0;
font-size: 4.2em;
letter-spacing: -0.02em;
text-shadow: 0 2px black;
}
```

And for the subheader just under it :

```
.helv, .bigtext {
font-family: "Open Sans",Helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 300;
letter-spacing: -.05em;
}
```

Comment: You are missing the big part where there is a  `text-shadow: 0 2px #FFFFFF;` declared on `.hp-banner-b h2`

Comment: Yes you're right, thank you. However, having this attribute on or off doesn't make any visible change on the page,  to me. This may have to do with my display settings/visual acuity, but I can't see the white shadow on the whitesmoke backgroud.

Comment: look better, cause it's the text-shadow that makes the text look good

Comment: I included text-shadow. However [this](http://ompldr.org/vZ3F0Ng/with.png) is the rendering made by the latest Google Chrome with text-shadow, and [this](http://ompldr.org/vZ3F0Nw/without.png) is the one without. I can't see the big difference "that makes the text look good".

Answer (score -1):

If you are speaking about the "14 million sites can’t be wrong." rendering, an easy way to do it it's to duplicate the title :

HTML:

```
 <div class="title"><h1>%%My title%%<span>%%My title%%</span></h1></div>
```

Then you have to place your fake span title under the real h1 one.

CSS:

```
.title h1 {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 0px;
    color: white;
}

.title h1 span {
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    left: -1px;
    color: black;
}
```

I think you can have your rendering this way.

**Edit** : Maybe a better way - you can use the [text-shadow CSS3 property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-shadow.asp)

Comment: this is a terrible way to do this. Google will index double texts in a `<h1>` It's simply using `text-shadow` css. There are work arounds for older IE versions

Comment: The text-shadow property is supported in all major browsers, except Internet Explorer(even the newer)

Comment: READ, I said there are work arounds for IE, example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4205516/933065

Comment: If this has to be done this way, I recommend doing it using Javascript rendering code.