# Browsers not rendering fonts correctly, anti-aliasing issue

Tags: css, fonts, webkit, antialiasing, google-font-api

I am facing some serious anti-aliasing problem while rendering my fonts over the browser, when I worked over by design in fireworks everything looks cool but now when I am using them as html/text and viewing them in browsers they are coming very jaggy and ugly in all major browsers I tested.
I am using two fonts here the lighter one is the `'Segoe UI Light'` & the bolder one is the `Roboto Slab`:

[image]

I searched over internet & SO and found few tricks which were meant to solve this but none worked for me here, you can see them in my CSS

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

`in .CSS`

```
body {
background-position: right;
background-position: top;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
font-family: 'Segoe UI Light', 'Century Gothic', Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-weight: normal;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
font-smooth: always;
text-shadow: #eee 0px 1px 1px;
-webkit-text-stroke: 1px;
-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
}

nav ul {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
width: 100%;
font-family: 'Roboto Slab','Segoe UI Light', 'Century Gothic', Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 19px;
text-align: center;
list-style-type: square;
}

nav li {
color: #FFF;
display: block;
float: left;
height: 36px;
text-transform: uppercase;
width: 200px;
margin: 15px 0 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A text shadow might help `text-shadow: #333 0px 0px 1px;`

Also try `-webkit-text-stroke: 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1)`

Comment: If you want to support text-shadow across IE browsers take a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205478/text-shadow-in-internet-explorer