# How can I convert this into a similar text shadow for IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, css

I am using this for non-IE browsers:

```
text-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #4C5157;
```

For IE 9 I am using:

```
filter: Shadow(Color=#4C5157, Direction=45, Strength=1);
```

But the shadow in IE is hideous.  How can I tweak it so that it looks like the way it does in non-ie browsers?

I looked here before:  [Text Shadow in Internet Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205478/text-shadow-in-internet-explorer)

But it doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: Which version(s) of IE?

Comment: What version of IE?  IE10 probably supports *real* CSS3 drop shadows.

Comment: @MikeChristensen Yes it does (See: http://caniuse.com/#search=text-shadow).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Text Shadow in Internet Explorer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205478/text-shadow-in-internet-explorer)

Comment: Sorry, updated question with version.  I am using IE 9.

Comment: @chris i looked at that before posting here.  it didn't work for me.

Comment: My opinion is let is look ugly on old versions of IE.  People need to learn to upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't test this live, but you might try this.

```
filter: glow(color=#4C5157,strength=1);
```

Comment: My dim memories of working with filters back when IE6 was the "new" browser seems to confirm there is some kind of glow filter that worked better than the hideous opaque text shadow CSS property. I should point out though that if you are going to answer questions you shouldn't be guessing - only post answers when its stuff you KNOW. Otherwise write a comment!

Comment: Didn't work properly.  looks as hideous as what i had.  Thanks though!

Comment: @Ennui I can't comment til 50 rep I guess otherwise I would. 

starbucks - I did find this site that could possibly aid you.
http://melaniededon.com/psd-to-css3/#sthash.Olg1X7yk.dpbs

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to support IE7 and IE6 you can use a .htc file, which will allow you to apply CC3 styling, including drop shadows.

You can find more info here:
http://css3pie.com

The about page shows you how to apply it:
http://css3pie.com/about/

All you'll have to do is link the .htc file like so:

```
#myElement {
    ...
    behavior: url(PIE.htc);
}
```